# Accessing an Instance's Variable from another Activity - Android Developement

Tags: android, eclipse

I have creted a program that has 3 Activities: MainActivity, UpgradeActivity and UpgradesActivity.

Main Activity contains a timer and it also contains an instance of a Vehicle class.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
TextView vehicleSpeed, vehicleName, vehicleDistance, vehicleLocation,
        vehicleStatus, vehicleNews, vehicleInfo, vehicleMoney;
ProgressBar vehicleFuel;
public static Vehicle vehicle;
boolean launched;
public static PartType selectedType;
Handler handler = new Handler();
```

I have a button in MainActivity, that when pressed will take me to a page where i can select which part of the vehicle i wish to upgrade. For example i select: Engine. The engine Button takes me to the Upgrade Activity. In this activity i can buy the upgrade which should be applied to the vehicle in MainActivity. For the purpose of this question, lets say it set vehicles speed to +3.

My question is in regards to how to access the vehicle instance inside the MainActivity from the UpgradeActivity. I've tried making the instance static but that didn't work. How do i gain access and how can i change the vehicles variables from the other activities.

Here is where i am making the instance:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.selectedType = PartType.Antenna;
    this.launched = false;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    vehicle = new Vehicle();
    vehicle.setupCar();
```

Here is where i am accessing the variable in Upgrades, it call the upgrade function inside of the Vehicle Class:

```
            buyUp1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) { 
                MainActivity.vehicle.upgradeEngine(MainActivity.vehicle.engineLvl + 1);
                Intent activityChangeIntent = new Intent(UpgradesActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                UpgradesActivity.this.startActivity(activityChangeIntent);
            }
        });
```

And this is the function within the Vehicle Class:

```
    public void upgradeEngine(int lvl) {
    engineLvl += 3;
    engine = parts.getEngine(lvl);
}
```

The vehicle Stores an integer called: EngineLvl. This determines what level the cars engine is. The level is incremented by +3 everytime the engine is updated.

The problem is that the engine level never changes. Even if i make the Vehicle instance and all of the variables within vehicle STATIC;

MAINACTIVITY:

Vehicle
Button to UpgradesActivity

UPGRADESACTIVITY:

Button to UpgradeActivity

UPGRADEACTIVITY:

Change vehicle enginelvl Int
Button back to MainActivity

Main>Upgrades>Upgrade

Thank you for your time

Comment: Post your code where u are 'making the instance static '.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say what is wrong without seeing the code, but I would advise you to use the Intent extras to move your data between activities. You will need to make your Vehicle class implement [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) (there is an example of how to implement Parcelable on that page, and countless others on the net). You pass your object as extra to the intent launching your UpgradeActivity like this :

```
Intent upgradeIntent = new Intent(this, UpgradeActivity.class);
upgradeIntent.putExtra("com.example.model.Vehicle", yourVehicleObject);
startActivityForResult(upgradeIntent, UPGRADE_CAR_REQUEST_CODE);
//UPGRADE_CAR_REQUEST_CODE is a unique private static final int
```

Then you can retrieve it in your UpgradeActivity onCreate method :

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Vehicle vehicleFromLastActivity = intent.getParcelableExtra("com.example.model.Vehicle");
```

Before going back to your MainActivity you do something like this :

```
Intent dataIntent = new Intent();
dataIntent.putExtra("com.example.model.Vehicle", yourModifiedVehicleObject);
setResult(RESULT_OK, dataIntent);
finish();
```

Then finally in MainActivity you need to handle the result, it is done like this :

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch(requestCode) {
    case UPGRADE_CAR_REQUEST_CODE:
        if(resultCode == android.app.Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Vehicle modifiedObject = data.getParcelableExtra("com.example.model.Vehicle");
                // Now you can use that object which is coming from UpgradeActivity
            }
    }
}
```

Of course this could cause issues if your Vehicle class takes a lot of memory. You could then consider passing only the relevant information through the Intent to rebuild the object in the UpgradeVehicle Activity, for example only the id & name.

Comment: So after changing the level of the vehicleFromLast activity i pass it back using the same method? And then i make the Vehicle in main equal to the new vehicle i passed back in?

Comment: My apologies, my answer could have been better. I edited to use startActivityForResult, which allows to retrieve an object from the UpgradeActivity when it is done with it. Let me know if you need more details ;)

Comment: Ill try all of that and get back to you :) Thank you

Comment: Im sorry this is causing some issues, since i have a bridging activity in between Main and Upgrade. Is there no way to statically access the value of engineLVl?

Comment: I would not recommend it, since it would mean to retain an instance of the MainActivity in memory while you open your other 2 Activities, and that is a bad idea (even described by some as "evil"), don't forget resources can be scarce on mobile. Depending on the number of Vehicles objects and their size, you could consider local storage, like SharedPreferences or even the device's SQLite database, more details here : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: Thank you ill have a look. Ill only be using one instance of Vehicle across the entire game. So i thought i can easily make it static. But if thats a problem then ill find another way.